# How to create a method in the MVC Controller so that it becomes AJAX Callable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How to create a method in the Controller so that it becomes AJAX Callable?

For example, code {0} can be accessed using {1} when the return type is ActionResult:

```
{0}:
public ActionResult TestWithActionResult(string id)
        {
            return View();
        }

{1}:
http://localhost:4574/ControllerName/TestWithActionResult/2
```

but my below code {3} can't be accessed with {4}:

```
{3}:
    public string TestWithString(string id)
            {
                return "some string";
            }
{4}:
http://localhost:4574/ControllerName/TestWithString/2
```

the id in the {3} is always null when I open {4}.

Should I decorate {3} differently? How?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult TestWithActionResult(string id)
{
    return Json("Some string");
}
```

Edit:

You can call the function using AJAX like this (using Jquery)

```
$.ajax( 
   url: 'http://localhost/TestWithActionResult/feed1',
   type:'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) { 
         //Process data
   },
   error: function(error) { }
);
```

Comment: How would you call it using AJAX from the client site?

Comment: How would you call it with @Html.RenderAction("TestWithActionResult");? you'd need to pass the parameter to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs to return an `ActionResult` of some kind (or `ViewResult`, `JsonResult`, etc) to be considered an Action. You could just use a `JsonResult` to write the text to the Response.

```
public ActionResult TestWithActionResult(string id)
{
  return new Json("some string");
}
```

Comment: JsonResult class is parameterless.

Comment: @William just return `Json("some string")`